# How can I fix a foldername in thai language showing up as "???" when I mapped a drive in freebsd

Tags: utf-8, freebsd, smb

I've a problem on freebsd mount_samfs when I use

```
$mount_smbfs -E utf-8:utf-8 -I SFILESHARE //user@SFILESHARE/docs /shared
```

So when I access from windscp to view these files I found folder **เทส** (Thai language) it show up ??? also I'm enter the folder ??? but in this folder is not show any file. How can I fix this problem on freebsd.

Comment: Ask this question on ServerFault to get a better response. Post the link here and I'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

This might be more of a terminal/locale setting.

What is your current shell and LANG set too?

You may want to use a terminal that properly supports UTF8 like sysutils/jfbterm or rxvt-unicode.